# Why is $p\Rightarrow q$ equivalent to $\neg p\lor q$ and how to prove it

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I don't know how to prove that $p\Rightarrow q$ is equivalent to $\neg p\lor q$ ,here is the link [p=>q](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=p%3D%3Eq) . And I don't know how wolframalpha generate "Minimal forms" .

Can you prove $p\Rightarrow q \equiv \neg p\lor q$,  and explain how to get "Minimal forms" ?

Thanks!

Comment: Okay, `=>` means implication, $\Rightarrow$. I take it that $||$ means "or", $\lor$?

Comment: yes thanks I'm new here

Comment: No problem. Want me to edit it to more standard mathematical notation?

Comment: yes thanks and how about the Minimal forms

Comment: There are algorithms for transforming propositional formulas into normal forms; see for example [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form#Converting_from_first-order_logic). Presumably, wolframalpha has programmed the algorithms in order to find the normal minimal forms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By definition, $p\Rightarrow q$ is true if and only if the consequence $q$ is true, or the antecedent $p$ is false. You can see it in the truth table that defines the implication. That is, $p\Rightarrow q$ is true if and only if either $\neg p$ is true, or $q$ is true; i.e., if and only if $\neg p\lor q$ is true (what you write as $!p||q$).

Or you can simply look at the truth tables. The truth table of $\neg p\lor q$ is the same as the truth table of $p\Rightarrow q$: true if $p$ and $q$ are false; true if $p$ is false and $q$ is true; false if $p$ is true and $q$ is false; true if $p$ and $q$ are both true:
$$\begin{array}{c|c||c}
p & q & p\Rightarrow q\\
\hline
0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 1
\end{array}\qquad\qquad
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
p & q & \neg p & \neg p\lor q\\
\hline
0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1
\end{array}.$$
The final columns are identical, so the two formulas take the same truth values given the same truth inputs: that is, they are propositionally equivalent.

Comment: Thanks a lot! have a nice day:)

Comment: @ArturoMagidin The question is why would the logical implication φ ⇒ ψ, read and understood as "*If φ, then ψ*", have the same truth values as the material implication φ ⊃ ψ.

Comment: @Speakpigeon: That might be *your* question, but it was clealry not the question that was asked and answered nine years ago. Thanks for the downvote, though, based on the fact that a decade ago I did not anticipate your wishes and desires.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Where does the question say "material implication"?

Comment: @Speakpigeon: The fact that the answer was accepted and that the person asking the question did not make any clarification should speak for itself. I’m very sorry that I failed to read your mind prospectively back then.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin You didn't have to read my mind. You only had to understand what the question meant from what it said. Where does the question says "*material implication*"?

Comment: @Speakpigeon: Again: the fact that I interpreted the question in the standard mathematical sense, **and that the asker agreed with that interpretation** should speak for itself. You’ve made your position clear: I was wrong to not read the question the way you think I should have, and I was wrong to answer the question to the asker’s satisfaction in a way that fails to satisfy you. Good for you. Consider your downvote your win, and you may take you ball and go home. Where does the question say I should answer *your* interpretation of it? Nowhere. You’ve emptily made your point. Move on.

Comment: @Speakpigeon: The “material implication” is the standard meaning of both $\implies$ and $\rightarrow$ in propositional calculus. The question is tagged propositional calculus. it doesn’t take a leap to interpret the symbol in a standard way. So sorry you aren’t satisfied.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Wikipedia says: "A ⇒ B means if A is true then B is also true".

Answer (score 1):

Using truth tables is a simple way to prove it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't reckon that you need a Truth Table. What do you reckon of the intuitive explanation beneath?

From: Philip Johnson-Laird [BA PhD Psychology (UCL)](https://dof.princeton.edu/about/clerk-faculty/emeritus/philip-nicholas-johnson-laird), Stuart Professor of Psychology Emeritus at Princeton.    (Author isn't  a logician.)    [*How We Reason  (1st edn 2008)*](https://www.amazon.ca/How-We-Reason-Philip-Johnson-Laird/dp/0199551332). p. 108.

I changed the author's choice of first names, to ones that start with P and Q to fit the title. I symbolized the disjunctions in square brackets.

> An exclusive
>   disjunction, such as:
>
> > Either Pia helped or Quinn helped, but not both
>
> is equivalent to the proposition:
>
> > Pia  helped or the Quinn helped, and not both Pia helped and the  Quinn 
> >     helped.
>
> Hence, exclusive disjunction also has a logical meaning.
>   In an analogous way we can define a logical meaning of “if”. The sentence:
>
> > If Pia  didn’t help then  Quinn  did. [If ¬P, then Q.]
>
> means:
>
> > Pia  helped or  Quinn  did, or both. [P ∨ Q]
>
> In its logical meaning, the conditional is compatible with three possibilities: Pia  didn’t help and Quinn did [¬P ∧ Q] , Pia  helped and Quinn didn’t [P ∧ ¬Q], Pia helped and Quinn helped [P ∧ Q]. The only possibility that the conditional
>   rules out is that neither the Pia nor Quinn helped [¬P ∧ ¬Q]. The three possibilities
>   that the conditional allows are the same as those for the inclusive disjunction.

Comment: You have only proved the trivial property (p → q) → (¬p ∨ q), which follows anyway from the definition of p → q as "*If p, then q*". To prove the equivalence (p → q) ⇔ (¬p ∨ q), you now need to prove (¬p ∨ q) → (p → q).