# What precisely is a vacuous truth?

Tags: logic, definition

Is there a proper and precise definition that goes something like this?

**Definition.** *A statement $S$ is a* vacuous truth *if ... ...*

Comment: [Wikipedia has a pretty good article about it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth).

Comment: The Wikipedia article seems a little imprecise and tentative. In particular, it states: *A statement S is* vacuously true *if it **resembles** ...*. As far as I know, "resembles" does not usually have any precise meaning in math or logic or philosophy. Indeed I was inspired by exactly that Wikipedia sentence to post this question here.

Comment: @MJD: I don't think much of the WP article.  It doesn't link its definitions to the sources it lists, and it does not relate to well-known related topics.  The claim 'A statement S is "vacuously true" if it resembles the statement $P \Rightarrow Q$, where P is known to be false' is unattributed, imprecise (resembles?, no outermost quantifier?, does "known" mean this is an epistemic claim?) and I would say is false (rather, vacuous truths "resemble" a special case of this form), and the well-known example is generally described as a paradox of material implication.

Answer (score 34):

No. The phrase "vacuously true" is used informally for statements of the form $\forall a \in X: P(a)$ that happen to be true because $X$ is empty, or even for statements of the form $\forall a \in X: Q(a) \to P(a)$ that happen to be true because no $a \in X$ satisfies $Q(a)$. In both cases, it is irrelevant what statement $P(a)$ is.

I guess you could turn this into a formal definition of a property of statement, but that's not standard.

Comment: I see. The reason I ask is that when asked "Why is $\emptyset$ a subset of every set?", many answer that the statement "Every element of $\emptyset$ is an element of the set $A$" is vacuously true, therefore $\emptyset \subset A$. But given your answer to my present question, it would appear to me that giving such a "vacuous truth" explanation is no explanation at all---it seems to be just saying that $\emptyset \subset A$ because $\emptyset$ is the empty set.

Comment: @KennyLJ I see; what you there have is a not totally formal argument that $\emptyset \subseteq A$. If you want to formalize it (which in my opinion doesn't answer the question *why?*, but does show that you can nail down everything to the last dot), you have to resort to, for instance, axiomatic set theory. There you'd have an axiom such as $\exists e \forall x [ x \not \in e]$. Given such an $e$ and another $a$, you can then prove $\forall x [ x \in e \to x \in a ]$ (i.e. $e \subseteq a$).

Comment: @KennyLJ But the explanation 'Every element of ∅ is an element of the set A" is vacuously true' does make sense. You still have a statement of the form $\forall a \in \emptyset. P(a)$ which is true because we're quantifying over the empty set; that fact that $P(a)$ is the statement $a \in A$ doesn't matter.

Comment: @KennyLJ, to show that $\emptyset$ is a subset of $X$, assume $a \in \emptyset$ and prove $a \in X$. Since $a \in \emptyset$ is a contradiction, thus [we may deduce anything](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion). Hence $a \in X$.

Comment: One can understand $(\forall a\in X)(P(a))$ as being a shorthand for  $(\forall a)(a\in X\to P(a))$.  This view unifies the “quantification over the empty set” and “antecedent is always false” explanations of vacuous truth.

Comment: @KennyLJ It's deeply unsatisfying to hear about all the members of an empty set: they're all invisible pink space unicorns, too! But: `A⊂B` can easily be transformed to `¬∃x[x∈A∧x∉B]`. Now, since `x∈A` is always false when `A=∅`, the conjunction is too, and the criterion is satisfied for all `B`. This way of putting it avoids the discomfiture of saying `∀x[x∈∅...`

Answer (score 16):

We say that an implication $p\to q$ holds vacuously if $p$ is always false. That is to say, it is impossible to have $p$ true and $q$ false. So the implication is a tautology.

Of course tautologies exist in propositional calculus, and not quite in predicate logic (and thus not in first-order logic), but the concept caries over.

So when we say that the empty set is a subset of $A$ is vacuously true, we say that there is just no counterexample to the contrary. Why is that true? Because the set is empty.

Comment: Couldn't we also deduce that the empty set is not a subset of $A$ then?

Comment: No. Given two sets $A$ and $B$, either $A$ is a subset of $B$ or it isn't. And until it is proved to be *not* a subset of $B$, it is one. If you want to prove that $\varnothing\nsubseteq A$, then you need to find a witness for that. But this witness is an element of the empty set which is not an element of $A$...

Comment: > And until [$A$] is proved to be _not_ a subset of $B$, it is one.

The reverse also seem like true: until $A$ is proven to be a subset of $B$, it is not.

Comment: @DmitryParzhitsky: Being a subset is a universal statement. Not being a subset is an existential statement. So what you're saying is not true.

Answer (score 14):

You are "not alone" with your doubt about $\emptyset$; see the "debate" in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/478021/mistakes-in-my-intuition-of-vacuous-truth-forall-x-in-emptyset).

You must "work with" Asaf's answer: basically, we have the definition of $\emptyset$ and that of inclusion :

> $A \subseteq B =_{def} \forall x (x \in A \rightarrow x \in B)$.

We have also a "basic principle" of mathematical reasoning (but not only) : "stay with the consequences of your assumptions, also when they are (a little bit) counterintuitive, unless you have found a contradiction (or a more satisfying theory)".

Let us try the "exercise" of negate the definition of set-inclusion : from $\lnot \forall x (x \in A \rightarrow x \in B)$, due to the fact that $\lnot \forall$ is equivalent to $\exists \lnot$ and that $p \rightarrow q$ is equivalent to $\lnot p \lor q$, we may "translate" the above formula into : $\exists x \lnot (\lnot x \in A \lor x \in B)$.

The final passage is with De Morgan, i.e.: $\lnot (p \lor q) \equiv (\lnot p \land \lnot q)$ and double negation, i.e.$\lnot \lnot p \equiv p$. Thus, we may transform the above formula into $\exists x (x \in A \land \lnot (x \in B))$.

Now we apply it with $\emptyset$ in place of $A$ :

> $\exists x (x \in \emptyset \land x \notin B)$.

What does it means ? That there exists an object $x$ that belongs to $\emptyset$ and ...

But we have **no** elements into $\emptyset$; thus, the "purported" negation of $\emptyset \subseteq A$ must be always false.

This is the "reason why" $\emptyset$ is a subset of every set.

In the above argument we have used the rules of logic: some of them are "refused" by some (few) mathematicians. You may not accept some (all) of them : it's up to you; in this way you may try to "escape" from asserting the unwanted property of the emptyset...

Comment: When I first prove to students that $\forall A(\varnothing\subseteq A)$ my experience is that first convincing them with a proof by contradiction is easy; then we can talk about vacuous truth and I can present the direct (or rather vacuous) argument.

Comment: But by the same logic, if we substitute A as ∅, we have:

A⊆B=def∀x(x∈A→x∈B).
This becomes:

∅⊆B=∀x(x∈∅→x∈B).

And since x∈∅ is always false, isn't it true that the empty set is never the subset of any set?

Comment: @DanielMak - NO : it is correct that $x \in \emptyset$ is always false, but the conditional $False \to P$ is *true*, for $P$ whatever. Thus $∀x(x \in \emptyset \to x \in B)$ is *always true* and this is exactly the reason why "the empty set is **always** subset of any set".

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thank you, I must have been drunk when I wrote that

Comment: Can you kindly address that which of the rules you used to prove that the empty set is a subset of all sets is not accepted by some mathematicians and why!? :)

Comment: @H.R. - see [Intuitionistic logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionistic_logic#Non-interdefinability_of_operators) for rejection of "full" De Morgan's lasw and equivalence between $p \to q$ and $\lnot p \lor q$ as well as interdefinability of quantifiers.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: Oooops! I am fearing that all the logic I know is false! :D So as a final word is $p \to q$ equivalent to $\lnot p \lor q$ or not!?

Comment: @H.R. - I'm not saying that :-) In the context of my answer, I considered as example of "vacuous truth" the fact that $\emptyset$ is a subset of every set. It sounds "unnatural" and counterintuitive; so, why do not stay with a different "convention" ? The gist of my final cpomment in that it is **not** a convention at all: assuming the *definition* of $\emptyset$ and using he *logical laws*, we prove it. Thus, we cannot "deny" it, unless we change the definition **or** (in principle) we reject some of "usual" logical laws. 1/2

Comment: There are some "school of thought" that propose to modify/limit the so called *classical* logical lwa; see e.g. [Intuitionistic Logic](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-intuitionistic/) and [Paraconsistent Logic](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-paraconsistent/). That's all.

Comment: What if we change the definition of set inclusion by breaking it into two cases. If $A \ne \emptyset$ the usual definition holds and if $A=\emptyset$ we make the convention that $A \subset B$ is always true for every $B$? :) Then we can avoid such arguments!

Comment: Mauro I think it will be a little more clear to complete the transformation and say that $\lnot x\in B\equiv x\notin B$.

Answer (score 8):

Not sure if this is as formal as you want, but it might be a step toward a formalization.

I generally think of it like this:

`A statement S is a vacuous truth if ...`

**S is formally true, but does not convey any information**.

The example I like for the layman is the "You're my favorite nephew" joke that is said by a person with only one nephew.  People understand it--what makes it funny is that it's true, but it doesn't mean anything.  (For example, this statement would also be true--"You're my least favorite nephew".)

To formalize it a bit, you can define favorite as follows:  "List all your nephews in order of preference, highest preference first.  The first nephew on the list is your favorite."  Then, in a list of one, that one is the favorite.  Similarly, "List all your nephews in order of preference, highest preference first.  The last nephew on the list is your least favorite."

The aunt is not lying--she is perfectly correct, by definition, in stating that the nephew is her favorite.  However, we would say that her statement "doesn't tell us anything".  In this case, it doesn't tell us anything because she has no other nephews.  What the nephew *wants* to think is "there is someone out there that she considers me superior to", but what turns out to be the case is that the nephew's reasoning is about an empty set--the set of nephews that she likes less than him.

From there, you might be able to get someone to see the (vacuous) truth of "Every person that has walked on the surface of the sun has survived."  Formally, it's accurate.  It's also formally accurate to say "Every person that has walked on the surface of the sun died instantly."  While both statements are *formally* true, they convey no information.

It might be too restrictive to say **S only tells us about members of the empty set**--because S might not tell us "things", or maybe not things "about members" of any set--but that would, I think, describe a class or collection of vacuously true statements.

Comment: I would suggest that you modify the claim that the opposite of "you're my favorite nephew" is "you're my least favorite nephew"

Comment: Thanks @Dunham.  I guess what you were getting at is that the actual "opposite" of that would be "you're not my favorite nephew", which would be false in this case?  Anyway, whether that's what you meant or not, it would be a possible inaccuracy so I reworded.  If it needs further clarification I welcome more feedback.

Comment: you're interpretation of my comment is correct. This is a nice intuitive explanation, I just thought it shouldn't stray too far from formal logic.

Answer (score 5):

An **implication** is said to be *vacuously true* if its antecedent is false.

$$\neg A \implies (A\implies B)$$

This logical principle is a tautology, and can be used to introduce an arbitrary consequent in an implication.

**Example 1**: If pigs can fly, then the President is a genius.

Proof: The antecedent, "pigs can fly," is false. Therefore the above implication is true, whether or not the consequent, "the President is a genius," is true. Note: We cannot infer from this that the President is not a genius. Nor can we infer the contrary that he *is* a genius.

**Example 2:** $\forall x: (x\in \emptyset \implies 0=1)$

Proof: $y\in \emptyset$ is always false. Then the implication $y\in \emptyset \implies 0=1 $ is true (vacuously so). Generalizing, we obtain as required: $$\forall x: (x\in \emptyset \implies 0=1)$$

Comment: Proof that $\neg A \implies (A \implies B)$ is tautology: $A \implies (B \implies C)$ is equal to $(A \land B) \implies C$, so $\neg A \implies (A \implies B)$ is equal $(\neg A \land A) \implies B$, which is equal to $\text{FALSE} \implies B$, which is true (regardless of the $B$'s truth value).

Answer (score 3):

Contrary to some of the existing answers, I don't have the impression that one typically speaks of a vacuous truth if the statement is a pure implication whose antecedent happens to be false; the usual use of "vacuous truth" occurs in the context of universal claims where the antecedent is *always* (i.e. for every object) false.

A universally quantified implication is vacuously true iff it is true just because there are no objects to satisfy the antecedent. Formally,

> A statement of the form $\forall u (\phi \to \psi)$ (where $u$ is a varible and $\phi$ and $\psi$ are arbitrary formulas) is vacuously true
> in a structure $\mathcal{S} = \langle \mathcal{D}, \mathcal{I} \rangle$
> iff
> for all $a \in \mathcal{D}$ and arbitarary $v$: $\mathcal{S},
>  v^{[u \mapsto a]} \not \models \phi$.