# Common notation for non vacuous implication

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Taking the definition of [vacuous truth](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/734418/what-precisely-is-a-vacuous-truth) to be an implication where nothing satisfies the antecedent. Is there notation commonly used for "non-vacuous implication"?

I could write:

$(\forall x . P(x) \implies Q(x)) \land (\exists x . P(x))$

But I need to write it a lot, so I would prefer to write some shorthand.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to consider using a $\LaTeX$ command such as \xrightarrow to create a symbol such as $\xrightarrow[]{\exists}$ or $\xrightarrow[]{\text{NV}}$ to denote 'non-vacuous implications'. For example, consider writing $$P(x) \xrightarrow[]{\text{NV}} Q(x)$$ in place of $\left(\forall x \ P(x) \rightarrow Q(x)\right) \wedge \left(\exists x \  P(x) \right)$.

Several Google searches concerning non-vacuous implications suggest to me that there may not be any notation commonly used for non-vacuous implications.