# Why is "$P$ only if $Q$" equivalent to "if $P$ then $Q$"?

Tags: logic, definition, propositional-calculus, intuition

Why is the statement "$P$ only if $Q$" equivelant to "if $P$ then $Q$"? Is there a paper explaining this in detail.

For instance, I know statement "$P$ is sufficient for $Q$" or "$Q$ is necessary for $P$" are equivalent to $P\Rightarrow Q$, since sufficient means "just enough" and $P$ need *not* be true for $P\Rightarrow Q$ to be true; however, necessary means "absolutely essential" and $Q$ *has* to be true for $P\Rightarrow Q$ to be true. Therefore, both statements translate to "if $P$ then $Q$".

In the case of "$P$ only if $Q$", [this following](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/958708/1176963) states that "$P$ only if $Q$" translates to "if not $Q$ then not $P$" and "if not $Q$ then not $P$" translates into "if $P$ then $Q$". The problem I don't understand is:

> Why does "$P$ only if $Q$" translate to "if not $Q$ then not $P$"?

Is there an intuitive explanation?

Comment: @TankutBeygu Yes, this answers the question. You can close as a duplicate.

Comment: It is a good practice to use the search facility of the site with the relevant tag added before posting a question.

Comment: I would say I tried looking this up on the internet but it didn't show me the original question.

Comment: @TankutBeygu I understand now.

Comment: [Trouble with 'only if'](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4404801/21813)

Comment: Example: It is raining ($R$) only if it is cloudy ($C$). This rules out that it is raining and not cloudy, i.e. we have $\neg (R\land \neg C)$ . Using a truth table, we can prove $\neg (R\land \neg C)\iff (R \implies C)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P$ can happen only if $Q$ happens.

So if $Q$ doesn't happen then $P$ can't happen.

"May I go to the movies?"

"Only if you have done your homework."

That is:

"If you don't do your homework then you may not go to the movies."